# building django template files with xslt

Tags: xslt, django-templates, escaping, lxml

I have about 4,000 html documents that i am trying to convert into django templates using xslt. The problem that I am having is that xslt is escaping the '{' curly braces for template variables, when I try to include a template variable inside of an attribute tag;
my xslt file looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:attribute name="nid"><xsl:value-of select="$node_id"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()"/>
    </p>
    <span>
        {% get_comment_count for thing '<xsl:value-of select="$node_id"/>' as node_count %}
        <a href="">{{ node_count }}</a> //This works as expected
    </span>
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">HControl</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">{% if node_count > 0 %}</xsl:text> // have to escape this because of the '>'
        <div class="comment-list">
            {% get_comment_list for thing '<xsl:value-of select="$node_id"/>' as node_comments %}
            {% for comment in node_comments %}
            <div class="comment {{ comment.object_id }}"> // this gets escaped
                <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">c{{ comment.id }}</xsl:attribute> //and so does this
                </a>
                <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                {% get_comment_permalink comment %}
                </xsl:attribute>
                permalink for comment #{{ forloop.counter }}
                </a>
                <div>
                {{ comment.comment }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

the output looks something like this:

```
<div>
<p nid="50:1r:SB:1101S:5">
    <span class="Insert">B.  A person who violates this section is guilty of a class 1 misdemeanor.</span>
</p>
<span>
    <a href="">1</a>
</span>
<div class="HControl">
    <div class="comment-list">
        <div class="comment '{ comment.object_id }'"> // this should be class="comment #c123"
            <a name="c%7B%7B%20comment.id%20%7D%7D"></a> // this should name="c123"
            <a href="%7B%%20get_comment_permalink%20comment%20%%7D"> //this should be an href to the comment
                permalink for comment #1
            </a>
            <div>
                Well you should show some respect!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I transform the file with lxml.etree and then pass the string to a django template object, and render it.
I just dont seem to understand how to get the xslt parser to leave the curly braces alone

Comment: BTW You should drop all of the `disable-output-escaping` attributes, they are wrong where you use them.

Comment: The first one is needed because the `>` gets escaped and causes django to crash while parsing the template, or is there another way? I will remove the others, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first one is indeed correct, there's no other way to do that.

Comment: FWIW, [here is the related follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684614/is-there-a-way-to-disable-urlencoding-of-anchor-attributes-in-lxml)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSLT has its own purpose for curly braces - they are used in [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), like this:

```
<!-- $someVariableOrExpression will be evaluated here -->
<div title="{$someVariableOrExpression}" />
```

To get *literal* curly braces into attribute values in XSLT, you need to escape them, which is done by doubling them:

```
<!-- the title will be "{$someVariableOrExpression}" here -->
<div title="{{$someVariableOrExpression}}" />
```

So if you want to output literal *double* curly braces, you need (guess what):

```
<div title="{{{{$someVariableOrExpression}}}}" />
```

Comment: doubling the curly braces works in `<div class="comment {{{{comment.object_pk}}}}">` but in the two anchor tags bellow that i am still getting the escaped curly braces i.e `<a name="{{{{comment.id}}}}"` is just giving me `<a name="%7B%7B%%7B%7B%comment.id%7D%7D%7D%7D">` whether I try to use the xsl attribute tag or just inline. I am obviously not very good at xslt :)

Comment: @Anvil: That's strange. Looks like the contents of `a.name` and `a.href` attributes gets URL-encoded automatically for some reason. Vanilla XSLT does not have an understanding of URL encoding, so this should not happen at all.

Comment: so the issue is probably with lxml?

Comment: @Anvil: Probalbly, yes. First, try adding `<xsl:output method="xml" />` to your sttylesheet. If that doesn't help: Can you use a different XSLT engine? Either that, or you check if there is a configuration option you don' know about (hat's good material for another question, add a three-liner code sample that reproduces just the error).

Comment: this is the correct answer for the question as i asked it. and it seems that the encoding is a feature not a bug ;) i'll ask another question, thanks